# Java code isn't working correctly: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I keep getting an error for this code I am working o. I would greatly appreciate anyone that can point out the problem I am having with this code. I have been working on it for hours with no luck. The error is below:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

The code that I have is as follows, it isn't working and I am very confused at the moment.

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
   int Soccer = 5;
   int[] jerseyNum = new int[Soccer];
   int[] ratingNum = new int[Soccer];
   int i = 0;
   char menuChar = 'b';
   int changedPlayer = 0;
   int newRating = 0;
   int ratingAbove = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < Soccer; ++i) {
         System.out.println("Enter player " + (i + 1) + "'s jersey number:");
         jerseyNum[i] = scnr.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Enter player " + (i + 1) + "'s rating:");
         ratingNum[i] = scnr.nextInt();
         System.out.println("");
    }
        System.out.println("ROSTER");
        for (i = 0; i < Soccer; ++i) {
        System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1) + " -- Jersey number: " + 
jerseyNum[i] + ", Rating: " + ratingNum[i]);
    }
    while (menuChar != 'q') {
     if (menuChar == 'o') {
        System.out.println("ROSTER");
     for (i = 0; i < Soccer; ++i) {
        System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1) + " -- Jersey number: " + 
jerseyNum[i] + ", Rating: " + ratingNum[i]);
            }
        }
     if(menuChar == 'a'){
        System.out.println("Enter a rating:");
     int rating = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println("ABOVE " + rating);
     for (i = 0; i < Soccer; ++i) {
     if(ratingNum[i] > rating) {
        System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1) + " -- Jersey number: " + 
jerseyNum[i] + ", Rating: " + ratingNum[i]);
                }
            }
        }
     if(menuChar == 'u'){
        System.out.println("Enter a jersey number:");
     int jerseynumber = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a new rating for player:");
     int rating = scnr.nextInt();
     for (i = 0; i < Soccer; ++i) {
     if(jerseyNum[i] == jerseynumber) {
        ratingNum[i] = rating;
        System.out.println("updated player");
        System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1) + " -- Jersey number: " + 
jerseyNum[i] + ", Rating: " + ratingNum[i]);
}
}
}
     if(menuChar == 'r'){
        System.out.println("Enter a jersey number:");
     int jerseynumber = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a new jersey number:");
     int newjerseynumber = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a rating for the new player:");
     int rating = scnr.nextInt();

     for (i = 0; i < Soccer; ++i) {
     if(jerseyNum[i] == jerseynumber) {
        jerseyNum[i] = newjerseynumber;
        ratingNum[i] = rating;
        System.out.println("raplaced player");
        //System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1) + " -- Jersey number: " + 
jerseyNum[i] + ", Rating: " + ratingNum[i]);
}
}
}
System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("MENU");
        System.out.println("u - Update player rating");
        System.out.println("a - Output players above a rating");
        System.out.println("r - Replace player");
        System.out.println("o - Output roster");
        System.out.println("q - Quit");
       System.out.println("");      
        System.out.println("Choose an option:");
        menuChar = scnr.next().charAt(0);
}
  return;
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to show which line throws this exception and what the input was.

Comment: InputMisMatchException occurs when you input a argument that doesn't matches the type scanner is expecting, like giving string when scanner expects .nextInt();

Comment: This is the full error Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at PlayerRoster.main(PlayerRoster.java:63)

Comment: and which line is line 63 ?

Comment: line 63 is: int newjerseynumber = scnr.nextInt();

Comment: "I keep getting an error" is it the same error each time?

Comment: Yes it is the same error

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

Comment: That still didn't fix my problem